# access xampp/htdocs directory from remote computer

Tags: directory, xampp, htdocs

I have installed a xampp server in a computer A.
now i want to access this xampp server from other computer B.i typed the ip address of the computer A ,where xampp server is installed , in the browser of computer B. i landed to the `**http://XX.XX.XX.XX/xampp**` page. now i want to access the htdocs directory but i am not able to access it.i used this path.

```
http://XX.XX.XX.XX/htdocs
```

and

```
http://XX.XX.XX.XX/xampp/htdocs
```

I am getting error

> Object not found

Somebody please explain what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to see the permitions of the xampp (they are blocked by default and you can see it at php.ini if i recall well) and the firewall of the computer B. After that, you should see the port of the xampp in the computer B and you should see the localhost of that computer.

If you are doing that in differents places, you should see if your operator allow you to see a ip remotely. In some countries are blocked too.

Comment: thanks for the answer . I am new for this xampp. Please tell me where to look in php.ini file ?
Firewall of both the computers are off.
Which ports of computer B should i see and how ?